# How to add image to ListView

Tags: android, eclipse, image, listview

Im trying to add some images to this ListView, but i cant find the way of doing it.
I also tried making a new ListView (which i saw in YouTube), and i cant make it open another activity xD

```
private void populateListView() {
    // Create list of items
    String[] items = {"Apps", "Games", "Other"};

    // Build Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mainitem, items);

    // Configure the list view
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void registerClickCallBack() {
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

            if(position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(viewClicked.getContext(), Apps.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if(position == 1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(viewClicked.getContext(), Games.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if(position == 2) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(viewClicked.getContext(), Other.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

If you know, please let me know ;)

Comment: Well you're going to have implement a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a custom adapter.
Try extending from BaseAdapter and implementing the interface [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)

> public class YourCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

You'll override various methods including 'getView' where you can inflate a layout that contains your image (for that position.

Next you'll set the adapter on your ListView like: yourListView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());

Here is the developer guide from google.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is custom adapter for you,

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


    private List<Location> locations;
    private static LayoutInflater inflator = null;


    public CustomListAdapter(List<Location> locations) {

        super();
        this.cp = 0;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.locations = locations;

        inflator = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.locations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        this.cp = position;
        View vi = convertView;

        try{

            if (convertView == null)
                vi = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_single_location_view, null);

            TextView locationName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.location_name);


            Location loc = locations.get(position);

            locationName.setText(loc.getName());

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("CustomListAdapter.getView",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return vi;
    }

}
```

Using Custom Adatper

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
locationListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this,locations);
list.setAdapter(locationListAdapter);
```

LocatioList.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

For each row item,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >


      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/news_image_title_ph"
            android:src="@drawable/place_holder_image"/>

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
        android:text="@string/location_name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/news_details" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

You can add image view as the TextView is added

Answer (score 0):

To add an image for every single row on a ListView you need to define a custom .xml file in which you have to create the layout of the single row, the way you want to show the image and the title/description. Then you have to extend the ArrayAdapter class so that you can inflate the row layout you created in the *getView* method you have to override when you redefine the ArrayAdapter class. So, in short:

1. Create your *row.xml* file like a normal layout file
2. Redefine *ArrayAdapter* class and in the *getView* method inflate the row layout defined

EDIT: take a look on this [page](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)